# Assertion 13111: field not found, expected type 9 threw by mongodb.

Tags: c++, mongodb, exception, assertion

Our mongodb sometimes throw the exception of assertion 13111:field not found, expected type 9 when we use mongodb c++ driver api to query some records from mongodb collection. We are sure that the records we demanded are correctly existed in the mongodb and our programme has no problem. Because, if you wait a moment and try the same query again or try the same query more times, it will recover normal and return complete correct records. So how to explain this strange phenomenon of mongodb? We will thanks a lot if you give us some constructive proposal or direct correct answer.

Comment: What MongoDB version and sort of deployment is this .. standalone, replica set, sharded cluster? Are you using read preferences? A code example of the query would help. It sounds like you may have a race condition where you are calling a function expecting a date field (type 9) to exist but retrieving your document before it does.

Comment: our deployment is sharded-cluster, and we use mongodb api in single thread.